# How do I delete a Kafka Consumer Group to reset offsets?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to delete a Kakfa consumer group so that when the application creates a consumer and subscribes to a topic it can start at the beginning of the topic data.

This is with a single node development vm using the current latest Confluent Platform 3.1.2 which uses Kafka 0.10.1.1.

I try the normal syntax:

```
sudo /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group my_consumer_group
```

I get the error:

```
Option [delete] is only valid with [zookeeper]. Note that there's no need to delete group metadata for the new consumer as the group is deleted when the last committed offset for that group expires.
```

If I try the zookeeper variant:

```
sudo /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --group my_consumer_group
```

I get:

```
Delete for group my_consumer_group failed because group does not exist.
```

If I list using the "old" consumer, I do not see my consumer group (or any other consumer groups)

```
sudo /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
```

If I list using the "new" consumer, I can see my consumer group but apparently I can't delete it:

```
sudo /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
```

Comment: there is no solution for this out-of-the-box

Comment: The shell can only delete ZK-based consumer groups. For groups of new consumer, you don't need to delete the groups since Kafka removes expired groups automatically. If you do want to reset the offsets for such groups, set `offsets.retention.minutes` to a smaller value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does an offset expire for an Apache Kafka consumer group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131465/how-does-an-offset-expire-for-an-apache-kafka-consumer-group)

Comment: There are plans to add support: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling

Comment: You can also do manual `Consumer#seekToBeginning()` in you application.

Comment: `seekToBeginning` is only offered in the Java API. It is definitely not in the Python API. And even in the Java API, it is less than ideal. Kafka 0.10.2 solves my underlying scenario in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading to the just released Confluent Platform 3.2 with Kafka 0.10.2 solved my underlying issue. When I delete a topic, offset information is now correctly reset. So when I create a topic with the same name, consumers start from the beginning of the new data.

I still can't delete new style consumer groups with the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool, but my underlying issue is solved.

Before Kafka 0.10.2, there were hacks, but no clean solution to this issue.

Comment: I can see still a large number of "Summed Recent Offsets" after I deleted and recreated my topics - do these get cleaned somehow?

Answer (score 23):

This can be done with Kafka 1.1.x. From the documentation:

`bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group my-group --group my-other-group`

Answer (score 9):

In Kafka 0.11 (or Confluent 3.3) you can reset the offsets of any existing consumer group without having to delete the topic. In fact you can change the offsets to any absolute offset value or timestamp or any relative position as well.

These new functions are all added with the new `--reset-offsets` flag on the `kafka-consumer-groups` command line tool.

See KIP-122 details here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling

Answer (score 4):

If you use Java client, you can first get the beginning offset.

```
TopicPartition partition = new TopicPartition("YOUR_TOPIC", YOUR_PARTITION);
Map<TopicPartition, Long> map = consumer.beginningOffsets(Collections.singleton(partition));
```

And the offset that consumer using to start processing, (if not delete the consumer group).

```
Long committedOffset = consumer.committed(partition).offset();
```

Now, if you think start from `committedOffset` is ok, just poll records.
if you want the beginning offset,
    consumer.seek(partition, map.get(partition));

Answer (score 1):

you can also reset the offset of single topic without deleting the entire consumer group :

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group my-group --topic my-topic --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Windows` and you need a JAAS config with password & username to access your kafka cluster, you can use the following commands

```
#consumer.properties
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" password="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```

```bash
.\kafka\bin\windows\kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server xxxxxxxxxx.confluent.cloud:9092 --group cop-group --topic topic_name_ini --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute --command-config .\kafka\config\consumer.properties
```

In the command above we used `--command-config` to pass a properties file for the JAAS config