# What happens if brokers in Kafka cluster have different settings?

Tags: apache-kafka

For example, let's say there is a discrepancy in `offsets.retention.minutes`, what setting becomes effective, from which broker? Does each broker have its own setting for partitions of `__consumer_offsets` that are hosted by that broker?

EDIT:
Apparently, I didn't understand what is `offsets.retention.minutes` setting for, I think I realized it after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027929/difference-between-retention-configuration-offsets-retention-minutes-and-log-ret) on SO.

I didn't understand the difference between that setting, and `log.retention.minutes` config for `__consumer_offset` topic, but now I think I do. Still, there may be some other settings that may be problematic if not set same on each broker in cluster?

Comment: Why would you like to have Kafka brokers with different configuration?

Comment: It's not that I would like it, I just wonder what happens if accidentally someone configures it differently. Is there some mechanism to prevent that? Or is there a mechanism that deals with that, built into Kafka cluster code?