# How can I consume data in a kafka topic after a particular timestamp in spring?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Say my spring consumer program went down I want to consume data from the time it went down. Is there any way to store the timestamp or the offset at that point and continue from there.

Kindly help,
Thanks in advance .

Comment: if you are committing the offset in your consumer, you dont need to maintain any offset. When you start your consumer again, it would start consuming from the point where it consumed last message successfully.

Answer (score 1):

**Ensure 3 things:**

- `group-id` should be same between restarts
- `auto.offset.reset` should be set as `latest`
- `offsets.retention.minutes` should be well defined. Read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027929/difference-between-retention-configuration-offsets-retention-minutes-and-log-ret) for more details for it.

[Kafka-Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) for reference